# Goodle AdSense ad not loading - how to prevent the call

Tags: azure, adsense, azure-application-insights

I have a website that utilizes Google AdSense. I have a single "responsive" ad unit that I place in multiple locations on my website, letting it figure out the size of ad to place in the specific location. This works great!

My website is running on Azure, and I have the default Application Insights stuff configured for telemetry information.

On the application map (in Application Insights inside Azure), I'm getting lots of dependency failures for googletagservices.com. Checking the uptime websites show that it hasn't been up for 11 months: http://downuptime.net/googletagservices.com.html.

The weird thing is, it's only throwing this error on 1 page in my website. And I'm also not able to reproduce it myself (I only have the logs). No other pages that I've tried tries pulling content from that domain (hence not being able to reproduce).

I'd like to not worry about this, and just tell Google AdSense to stop loading ads from via that URL, is there a way to configure my Google AdSense account to not load content from that domain? Everything I've read just says to use AdBlock plus or something like that to stop loading ads from that site, but that's from the consumer perspective, I'm the website guy, I want to stop showing it TO the consumers...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the cause of this issue finally...

When using Google Adsense's "responsive" ads on a responsive website is sometimes tricky. The problem with my scenario is I'm hiding particular ads based on the different screen sizes.

For example, when on a mobile device (xs in bootstrap), then I don't show the header ad across the top of the page, would take too much space. In this instance, when you are on a mobile device, then that area/parent container for the header has the height and width set to 0. Then, when Google Adsense goes to fetch the ad to display (even though it's going to be hidden), it realizes that the place that it needs to put the ad is not big enough for it, thus throwing the error.

The fix for this is to set minimum sizes of the parent containers so they will always have enough space to place the ad.

Also, [this link](https://www.alltechbuzz.net/custom-display-of-ads-on-desktop-and-mobile/) shows that you should also not even request the ad unless the parent container will be displayed. So for my example, don't even request that header ad when viewing on a mobile device, since the container wouldn't be big enough to hold the ad anyway.